# SharePoint 2013 "sorry, something went wrong" error

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Every time I try to edit the homepage of a sub site, I get this error:

---

> Sorry, something went wrong
>
> An unexpected error has occurred.
>
> Web Parts Maintenance Page: If you have permission, you can use this page to temporarily close Web Parts or remove personal settings. For more information, contact your site administrator.
>
> TECHNICAL DETAILS
>
> Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.
>   Correlation ID: e600839c-9ba3-8086-3aaa-67ad6e8baef0
>
> Date and Time: 4/1/2014 8:21:33 AM

---

I'm fairly new to SharePoint. If anyone could shed some light on this, it will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty generic error in SharePoint that can be caused by any number of things.  You can take a look a the Web Parts Maintenance Page by adding "?content=1" to the URL of your page.  If you recently added a web part to the page or some other customization, this will allow you to turn it off.

More than likely though, you will have to do some digging.  Whenever you ih that page and get an error, you get a correlation id like in your example above.  You can dig deep into the logs by finding them (typically in C:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\web server extensions\15\logs).  Look for the most recent file and do a search it in and see if you can find that correlation id.  If you can't find it you might try the previous log.  When you find matching entries for the correlation id, you should get some idea to the component that is failing and causing your issues.

Answer (score 1):

As odd as this sounds it worked to fix this for us.....

I had imported calendars from sharepoint 2003 to sharepoint 2013.

We had a reoccurring calendar appointment that would trigger in sharepoint 2013. The "Sorry, Something went wrong" Web Parts Maintenance Page: If you have permission you can use this page blah blah blah.... error would trigger for us on only the reoccurring appointments that were imported from SP 2003.

We deleted the reoccurring appointment in the SP2013 calendar and restored it from the  settings - site contents - recyclebin (user who deletes must do the restore) and for some odd reason all the appointments were now opening and all content was still there.

Maybe this will help someone